# Kendo UI Chart making the crosshair sticky

Tags: svg, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

When using the Kendo Dataviz, chart I need to have the crosshair stick, and to be calibrated between plot points on the category axis.

On the hover over the crosshair will lose stickiness, and always aligns to gridline, with the below code:

```
var chart = $("#" + d.obj_map[objId].upstream).data("kendoChart");
var hair = chart._plotArea.crosshairs[0];
hair.stickyMode = true;
```

The other problem with the crosshair is to able to set it between plot... So I though drawing my own crosshair on the chart.

```
var m = hair.linePoints();
var opt = hair.options;
        opt.zIndex = 100;
        var view = chart._view.createLine(m[0].x, m[0].y, m[1].x, m[1].y, opt);
        var jk = view.renderPoints();
```

neither one is working properly. Does anyone know how to draw custom lines on Kendo chart?